# Apache2 VHOST matches wrong server name

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

I'm running Apache 2.4.54 on Debian Bullseye and have 42 VHOSTs configured. Most of them are subdomains xxx.my.domain.com of our main domain, say my.domain.com. One client has a special domain. There is also a default VHOST to catch all the requests. All the VHOSTS reside in numbered files, the default comes last.

- HTTP -> HTTPS
- subdomain not catches before -> ErrorDocument
- no subdomain -> errorDocument

In the case I just enter https://my.domain.com, this request is catched by one of the earlier vhosts and not by the default VHOST. I don't understand why this happens.

Without SSL, the request is answered by 99-default.conf

**99-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        ServerName my.domain.com
        Redirect permanent / https://my.domain.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_access.log vhost_combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias *.my.domain.com
        Redirect 404 /
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ErrorDocument 404 "Subdomain does not exist"
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>



# match requests without subdomain
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName my.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Redirect 404 /
        ErrorDocument 404 "Please choose subdomain"
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# match any subdomain that does not exist (that's why order is important)
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAlias *.my.domain.com
        Redirect 404 /
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ErrorDocument 404 "Subdomain does not exist"
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**02-app-customer.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    ServerAlias customers-domain.com
#    ServerAlias customer.my.domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard_chain.crt

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_access.log vhost_combined

    Include conf.d/security.conf
    Include /usr/local/app/local/customer/httpd.conf

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-app.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>

</VirtualHost>

# Redirection from port 80 to 443 if ssl enabled
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName customers-domain.com
#    ServerAlias customer.my.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.customers-domain.com/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_access.log vhost_combined
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect of www.customers-domain.com to customers-domain.com
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    ServerName www.customers-domain.com
    ServerAlias www.customers-domain.biz
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard_chain.crt
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_access.log vhost_combined
    Redirect permanent / https://customers-domain.com        
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.customers-domain.com
    ServerAlias www.customers-domain.biz
    Redirect permanent / https://customers-domain.com/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app_access.log vhost_combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't understand why a request to https://my.domain.com is catched by 02-app-customer.conf and not by 99-default.conf. Any ideas?

Comment: Your VirtualHost for `customers-domain.com` is missing the `ServerName` directive.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VirtualHost for customers-domain.com:443 is missing the ServerName directive.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    ServerName customers-domain.com
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```